# spring cloud stream - consumer group bound

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, kafka-consumer-api, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

My consumer is bound to anonymous consumer group instead of consumer group I specified.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost
          defaultBrokerPort: 9092
          zkNodes: localhost
          defaultZkPort: 2181
        bindings:
          inEvent:
            group: eventin
            destination: event
          outEvent:
            group: eventout
            destination: processevent
```

My Spring boot applicaition

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(EventStream.class)
public class ConsumerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }
    @StreamListener(value = "inEvent")
    public void getEvent(Event event){
        System.out.println(event.name);
    }
}
```

My input output channel interface

```
public interface EventStream {
    @Input("inEvent")
    SubscribableChannel inEvent();
    @Output("outEvent")
    MessageChannel outEvent();
}
```

my console log--

> : Started ConsumerApplication in 3.233 seconds (JVM running for 4.004)
>   : [**Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=anonymous.0d0c87d6-ef39-4bfe-b475-4491c40caf6d]** Discovered
>   group coordinator singh:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
>       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=anonymous.0d0c87d6-ef39-4bfe-b475-4491c40caf6d] Revoking
>   previously assigned partitions []
>       : partitions revoked: []
>       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=anonymous.0d0c87d6-ef39-4bfe-b475-4491c40caf6d] (Re-)joining
>   group
>       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=anonymous.0d0c87d6-ef39-4bfe-b475-4491c40caf6d] Successfully
>   joined group with generation 1
>       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=anonymous.0d0c87d6-ef39-4bfe-b475-4491c40caf6d] Setting newly
>   assigned partitions [inEvent-0]
>       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=anonymous.0d0c87d6-ef39-4bfe-b475-4491c40caf6d] Resetting
>   offset for partition inEvent-0 to offset 2.
>       : partitions assigned: [inEvent-0]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `group` property must not be in the `kafka` tree.
It has to be like this:

My consumer is bound to anonymous consumer group instead of consumer group I specified.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
       bindings:
          inEvent:
            group: eventin
            destination: event
```

See more info in the Docs: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.1.1.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream.html#consumer-groups

The `group` is a common property, so it is the same independently of the binder implementation. The `kafka` is for Apache Kafka specific properties, exposed on its binder implementation level.